# MVP - O que fica aonde?

Tags: android

to com uma duvida sobre o MVP.
Nos meus estudos compreendi que no M = Model fica tudo aquilo que tem haver com regras de negócio e codigos de manipulação dos dados relacionados ao negócio, acesso a banco, adapters etc.
No P = Presenter fica a apresentação, ou a interação entre o Model e o View para manipular, mastigando o que deve ser mostrado. 
E o View é a visualização!

Mas no Android temos por exemplo métodos nativos do android como o onRequestPermissionsResult, OnClickListener listenerTvAddDetalhesRotulo, onActivityResult. 
Esses itens ficaria na apresentação ou no modelo?

Ou por ser itens nativos do android deixo como esta na activity mesmo?

Comment: Não tem outra alternativa senão deixá-los na Activity. Pode/Deve é delegar a resposta a eles para código no Presenter.

Answer (score 1):

O ***model*** é responsável pelos dados que serão exibidos na interface do usuário. Poderíamos considerar como modelo, além dos dados, qualquer lógica de manipulação e acesso destes dados.

O ***view***, normalmente implementado por uma `Activity`(também pode ser um `Fragment` ou qualquer elemento UI, dependendo da estrutura da sua aplicação), vai conter uma referência para o *presenter*.  O *presenter* pode ser criado pela *Activity* ou fornecido via injeção de dependência. A única responsabilidade da *View* é chamar métodos no *Presenter* toda vez que o usuário interage com ela.

O ***presenter*** age como intermediário entre a *view* e o *model*. Ele retira os dados do modelo e retorna para a *view*. Mas, diferente de típicos MVC, ele também decide o que acontece quando usuário interage com a *view*.

Essas definições acima foram extraídas do [artigo de Antonio Leiva](http://antonioleiva.com/mvp-android/).

Quanto aos métodos `onRequestPermissionsResult`, `OnClickListener`, `onActivityResult`; devem ser mantidos nas suas respectivas atividades ou fragmentos, fazendo parte da *view* em relação ao MVP, que também se encontram em classes do próprio Android. Já o método  `listenerTvAddDetalhesRotulo`, que provavelmente você inventou, dependendo do contexto, pode entrar no *presenter* ou *model*.

Se estiver interessado em boas práticas se tratando de Android, recomendo ler [Best practices in Android development](https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices).

Comment: Por exemplo, se eu tenho na activity um método chamado

public boolean verificarCampos(Car car) {...}
que verifica se os campos estão preenchidos e retorna um boolean para indicar a resposta dessa verificação, isso deveria ficar no model ou no presenter?

Comment: Neste caso, vai depender muito do que o método vai fazer. Poderia inserir no Model ou no Presenter. `VerificarCampos()`, seria algo como validação certo?! Então poderia sim inseri-lo no Presenter. Veja este artigo, pode dar mais uma esclarecidada; http://blog.karumi.com/interfaces-for-presenters-in-mvp-are-a-waste-of-time/

Comment: mas o verificarCampos eu preciso dos EditText por exemplo para verificar se estão preenchidos mas eles estão na Activitiy, como vou verificar eles dentro do presenter?

Comment: Você pode passar os EditText por parâmetro, por exemplo VerificarCampos(editTextSenha); E dentro você faz a validação. Isso caso você queira que o EditText tenha alguma reação, como por exemplo mudar a cor do fundo caso não seja validado.